# In Vimscript, is it possible to access information known by the syntax highlighter?

Tags: python, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

For example, if I am writing a Vimscript function to operate on Python syntax, it might be useful to know whether a line is regular code, a comment, or enclosed in triple-quotes. I assume that the syntax highligher has already figured out such things. Can I easily access that information in my own Vim functions, or do I have to roll my own parsing logic?

```
def eight_the_hard_way():
    '''
    Blah blah.
    '''
    # Blort!
    x = 4 + 4
    return x
```

I've searched a fair bit for this information, but haven't found anything directly on this topic so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, with the `synID()` function, you can obtain the syntax ID at a particular cursor position.

There are two complications:

1. You usually want to compare against a particular highlight group (e.g. `Comment`)
2. Because of syntax nesting, there can actually be an entire stack of syntaxes at a position.

The `:help synID()` has additional hints and pointers how to solve these.
My [ingo-library plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433) provides a convenient `ingo#syntaxitem#IsOnSyntax( pos, syntaxItemPattern )` function for that.

Also, check out the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin. It is an indispensable debugging aid.